# How to insert 20 dates for each cell in a column

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have been given an excel column with numbers and I want to create a new column with every cell content repeating 20 times and 20 dates sequentially next to it to another column. 

How can I achieve this in excel or access?

For example I have a column with numbers as follows:

0491703316 
 
0235361458 
 
0380458968 
 
0240510098 
 
0169346827 
 
0147826672

and I want to do this

0491703316 **01/12/2016**
 
0491703316 **02/12/2016**
 
0491703316 **03/12/2016**
 
0491703316 **04/12/2016**
 
......................
......................
0235361458 **01/12/2016**
0235361458 **02/12/2016**
0235361458 **03/12/2016**
0235361458 **04/12/2016**
 
........................
........................
........................
0380458968 
 
0240510098 
 
0169346827 
 
0147826672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link the range in Access as a linked table named, say, *LinkedTable*.

Then create this query:

```
PARAMETERS 
    Period Text ( 255 ), 
    Periods Short, 
    FirstDate DateTime;
SELECT DISTINCT
    LinkedTable.Number, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1 As Sequence,
    DateAdd([Period],[Sequence]-1,[FirstDate]) AS [DateStart]
FROM 
    LinkedTable,
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)<[Periods]
```

Run this with the parameters:

```
Period: d
Periods: 20
FirstDate: 2016-12-01
```

Comment: Adopted from: [Create a date table between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311939/create-a-date-table-between-2-dates/43316721#43316721).

Comment: There is a problem though. The sequence goes 1, 2, 3 and then jumps to 11, 12.... up to 20. Same for dates. So it's missing 4 to 10!

Comment: That is weird. Which Access version?

Comment: Access 2013 under windows XP

Comment: Are you sure? Not even Vista is supported for Access 2013.

Comment: sorry windows 7 wanted to say.

Comment: Found out. You have removed the `PARAMETERS` section, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `0491703316` is in A1, in B8 enter `01/12/2016` and copy down to B28. Copy B8:B28 to B29. Select B8:B29 and drag down to B133. In A8 enter `=A1` and in A9:

```
=IF(B9=B$8,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A8,A:A,0)+1),A8)
```

Copy A9 down to suit.