# Return sums even if no data exist in given day

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table with amounts only on some days, e.g.:

```
[DATE] [AMT]
11/1/2017 $123
11/1/2017 $50
11/3/2017 $123
```

How can I query the data and get:

```
11/1/2017 $173
11/2/2017 $0
11/3/2017 $123
```

I tried like:

```
SELECT Day([Date]) AS [Day], Nz(Sum(AMT),0) AS [Day Total]
FROM mytable
WHERE Month([Date])=11
GROUP BY Day([Date]);
```

But still it doesn't return 0s for days without data, any ideas?

Comment: For once, I'd go with a RIGHT JOIN; `mytable right join calendartable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Access*, you can create a series of dates between the first and the last date, and then create an outer join to your summed data.

Here is how to create the date series:

[Create a date table between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316721/3527297)

Answer (score 1):

You need a table with all the days, so you can fill the holes, lets call it `allDays`

[Get a list of dates between two dates using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function)

Then your query is:

```
 SELECT a.[date], COALESCE(SUM([AMT]),0)
 FROM allDates a
 LEFT JOIN yourTable t
   ON a.[date] = t.[date]
 GROUP BY a.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple solutions.

- Join to a table with all dates in the month, as in Juan's answer.
- [Use this query by user RedFilter to generate the dates.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/4897271)

Comment: I forgot to mention that is MS Access 2016 SQL so not all TSQL functions are available, e.g. the RedFilter complains about reserved words and the COALESCE above doesn't exist in Access, that's why I used Nz()

Comment: @PizzaChip In that case I would go with a date series table. What date range are you using in your data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%b") AS month, SUM(total_price) as total
FROM table
WHERE date <= NOW()
and date >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y"))
```