# Dummy columns having sequential numbers in SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, pivot

I am trying to create dummy columns having sequential numbers in SQL query or in ADO using Excel VBA.

```
SEQ1 = some Sequential number e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6....100
SEQ2 = some Sequential number e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7....100
```

Query:

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(F2.Textval) AS Textval
SELECT SEQ1 AS DUMMY1, SEQ2 AS DUMMY2, COUNT(F2.Position) AS Pos, F1.Name AS Name
FROM FILE1 AS F1 INNER JOIN FILE2 AS F2
ON F1.ID = F2.ID
GROUP BY F1.Name
ORDER BY F1.Name, F2.Position
PIVOT F2.Position IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...100)
```

**Output:**

Q.1] Is there a way to create these dummy columns purely in an SQL Query without using primary key? I don't want to write loops in Excel VBA to create a sequence.

Output should look like this:

```
DUMMY1    DUMMY2    Pos    Name    1        2        3        4        5....
==============================================================================
0         1         78     AB     OBIW      SDMS     SDED     GSAS     SDSQ...
1         2         12     DS     ZASY      SEEW     QTSA     RYUD     SOPH...
2         3         33     EF     QWET      DJMS     WDUD     JSAS     SDJL...
3         4         60     AC     ALJJ      BDMS     AUUD     AWAS     EDST...
4         5         02     JK     ADGH      VDWS     CARD     ARAF     SNSS...
...
```

Q.2] Can below sequence be written purely in an SQL Query instead of coding it in Excel VBA?

```
PIVOT F2.Position IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...100)
```

Currently, I am creating this sequence in VBA:

```
NumSeq = JOIN([TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:100))], ",")

...PIVOT F2.Position IN NumSeq
```

Comment: You can't do this easily. Review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316721/7296893) for a sequence generator. But for your purposes, a running count of IDs might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Erik A, how do I integrate SysObjects into my code which is running in Excel vba?

Comment: MSysObjects is just a table. You can query off it like any. If you want a working connection string to work with MSysObjects, you can just call `?CurrentProject.Connection` from the immediate window in Access, and copy-paste that string

Comment: I think by mistake I mentioned Access, but I am working in Excel VBA.

Comment: What's the RDBMS you're working with then?

Comment: Not working with any rdbms. Just ADO in Excel. I use access to only write and test the query.